# Error: 'AnimatedScale' is imported from both /implicit_animations.dart' and 'package:flutter_neumorphic/src/widget/animation/animated_scale.dart'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have upgraded to flutter 2.5.2 now facing this issue in 2 library unable to use as keyword because they library specific

I am unable to run the app

Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_neumorphic-3.1.0/lib/src/widget/button.dart:200:14: Error: 'AnimatedScale' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/widgets/implicit_animations.dart' and 'package:flutter_neumorphic/src/widget/animation/animated_scale.dart'.
      child: AnimatedScale(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_neumorphic-3.1.0/lib/src/widget/switch.dart:167:20: Error: 'AnimatedScale' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/widgets/implicit_animations.dart' and 'package:flutter_neumorphic/src/widget/animation/animated_scale.dart'.
            child: AnimatedScale(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/flipitnews/Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1005

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/flipitnews/Downloads/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Seems like there is a widget which you made and is called AnimatedScale and the package you are using also have the same name for a widget AnimatedScale. What you can do is remove your import if you don't need it or if you really need both of the packages specify the name for one of them - import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/implicit_animations.dart' as myWidget. Then you can call myWidget.AnimatedScale and the compiler will have no objections to that.

Comment: i haven't create the AnimatedScale it is from flutter and another AnimatedScale is from library its not possible to change import as myWidget in both classes because they are not defined by me.

Comment: Neither is for example dart:html, but you can define it like this: import 'dart:html' as html and then you can call classes and functions like this: html.Blob(just an example), even if you made your own Blob class.